# The specified glob pattern does not match any file or the default test directories are empty. - testcafe

Tags: typescript, testing, ui-automation, glob, testcafe

I have started learning testcafe, as our organization wanted to invest time on R & D on getting new e2e tools for angular automation.

I am trying to create an initial small test and facing the following error.

I have installed the testcafe locally using the command

```
npm install --save-dev testcafe
```

and have created a spec file with name `first-test.spec.ts`

```
import { Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture`Getting Started`.page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test("My First Test", async t => {});
```

when using the following command to run the test

```
npx testcafe chrome tests/
```

I am getting the following error

[image: s]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create test folder and place your spec file in tests, folder and then try to execute the same command

```
npx testcafe chrome tests/
```

Comment: It's non descriptive message. The problem was in my case a wrong path to the test files